how to reduce cognitive complexity of these condition in java?
I have set alot of values like this in my code using builder function but everywhre on && and ? operators I m getting sonarLint cognitive complexity issue.
here
AppointmentDetailsInfo appointmentDetails =(newAppointmentDetailsDTO !=null &&newAppointmentDetailsDTO.getData()!=null && newAppointmentDetailsDTO.getData().getAppointmentDetails()!=null) ?newAppointmentDetailsDTO.getData().getAppointmentDetails():null;

and here also
isNewPatient(gosDTO != null ? gosDTO .getIsNewPatient() ? 1 : 0 : null);
referredProviderName(gosDTO != null ? gosDTO .getReferredProviderName() : null);
isMobile(gosDTO != null ? gosDTO .getIsMobile() : null);

how it can be correct?

Per your original post, using Optional chaining should be one way to address the complexity. Did that not resolve the linting? Otherwise, making each of the getters return Optional on their own would reduce the amount of null checks

Code with that many null checks is very fishy. Why would the newAppointmentDetailsDTO ever be null for example? It's a data transfer object... it's job is to transfer data. It should never be null. Data inside it might be null though, if there is no data to speak of.

as it is about "sonarLint cognitive complexity" I vote to re-open as not opinion based

How can it be correct?  Because in the opinion of the people who coded SonarCube, both of those examples are cognitively complex.  I don't know if they are using a standard complexity measure (e.g. cyclomatic complexity) or not, but even if they are these measure don't have a strong theoretical bases.  (How do you cater for the fact that different people think ... and read code ... differently?)

If you don't agree with SonarCube's method of assessing complexity, just turn that aspect off.  (After discussing it with your co-workers of course.)

Related: What is Cognitive Complexity in sonar report?

I'm not entirely sure what I think about Sonar's cognitive complexity measure, but I don't think it is wrong to penalize use of the ternary operator.  That almost always makes code harder to understand, and it should be avoided (IMO) anywhere that it is not a very clear win.

I think in java you don't have any way to simplify that.
